# count of number of occurrences of the words in the sentence passed to the method

Tags: apex, class

How do I code a method which expects a string and prints the count of number of occurrences of the words in the sentence passed to the method.

Sample Input/Output :

```
Input : My Name is good and I like my name
Expected Output :
I - 1
Name - 2
```

How do I find the count of number of occurrences of the words?

I have tried this so far:

```
public class Problem1 {
    public void testmethod(){
    List<String> inputStr = new List<String>();
    String inputStr[]  = inputStr.split('');
    Set<String> SetString = new Set<String>(inputStr);

        for(String str : inputStr ){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please take a quick look at [ask] and come back to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is an APEX string method that does exactly this:

[APEX string methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

> **countMatches(substring)** 
>   Returns the number of times the specified substring occurs in the current String.
>   **Signature**
>   public Integer countMatches(String substring)

So in your case:

```
String input = "My name is good and I like my name";
String subStr = "I";

input.countMatches(subStr); //should return 1

String subStr = "name";

input.countMatches(subStr); //should return 2
```

Comment: This pre-supposes you know the word(s) to count. sfdcfox's version meets the stated requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a Map for this purpose.

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();
for(String word: inputStr.split('\\s+')) {
  Integer wordCount = wordCounts.get(word);
  if(wordCount == null) {
    wordCount = 0;
  }
  wordCounts.put(word, wordCount+1);
}
```

If case-sensitivity does not matter, make sure you convert to a common case:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();
for(Sting word: inputStr.toLowerCase().split('\\s+')) {
  Integer wordCount = wordCounts.get(word);
  if(wordCount == null) {
    wordCount = 0;
  }
  wordCounts.put(word, wordCount+1);
}
```

The output would look like this:

> {and=1, good=1, i=1, is=1, like=1, my=2, name=2}

Comment: For performance I would do the toLowerCase once before splitting the string.

Comment: @PhilW For small payloads, it wouldn't matter significantly, but I totally agree that would be the preferred way to do so. I've edited this answer to reflect that.